# How to add SSL certificate in core java?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

My requirement is simple. I have SSL certificate for website. I want to connect to that website through https but i want to do this through simple java class (without Keystore as do not want to do any change in installed java). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

All JREs ship with an default truststore (`cacerts`) that contains most Certificate Authorities (CAs) that you'd typically use on a website.

If your website uses a valid SSL certificate issued by a CA that is trusted by your version of Java, then you can connect without having to configure your truststore.